# cin.getline() skips

Tags: c++, getline, cin

Ok here is a very simple question:
In the following code section, the "cin.getline()" doesn't run:

```
cout<< "Specify USB drive letter: ";
char usbD[1];
char outputLoc [40];
cin.getline(usbD, 1, '\n');
cout<< "\n" << usbD << "\n";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just `char usbD; std::cin >> usbD;`?

Comment: **Always** check the result of read operations once you have attempted to read something. You would have noticed that the `std::cin.getline()` actually *is* run but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 spaces to store a string with a single character, this is because c++ uses a `\0` to delimit the string. You can change your code as follows:

```
cout<< "Specify USB drive letter: ";
char usbD[2];
char outputLoc [40];
cin.getline(usbD, 2, '\n'); // the 2 here will be the drive letter and the ending \0
cout<< "\n" << usbD << "\n";
```

Comment: right i forgot to include space for the terminating character, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need usbD[2] - for the letter and end of string `'\0'`.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/

- istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
- istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );

> ```
> s
>     A pointer to an array of characters where the string is stored as a c-string.
>
> n
>     Maximum number of characters to store (including the terminating null character).
> ```

Answer (score 0):

@PiotrNycz is right, you didn't leave room for the terminating null. But if all you want is one character, there's no reason to use an array.

```
char usbD;
cin.get(usbD);
```